# cutting structured numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Hello numpy masters of the world. I would like to find a better solution for the following task.
One has a structured array:

```
from pylab import *
data    = np.zeros((3,),dtype=( [('value1', 'i4'), ('value2', 'f4'),('name','S6')] ) )
data[:] = [(1,2.,'Hello'),(2,3.,"World"), (4, 5, "year")]
```

I often find my self searching in the data array for a line like this:

```
line  = data[data["name"]=="World"]
```

The next thing I would like to achive is to strip the line by "name". So I do:

```
names = line.dtype.names
sline = line[ [name for name in names][:-1] ]
```

And to get the values

```
result = sline[0]
print result
(2, 3.0)
```

As you can see this is a relative complicated and not very readable way.
The problem is, that a line of a structured array is not slicable (line[0][:-1] does not work).
This leads to the line with names and the need to loop over them to be able to cut. 
All this is way easier if data is a normal numpy array without the structure, because one can use the powerfull cutting syntax here.
On the other hand I like the possibility of finding values in a structured array by calling there names rather then cryptic index numbers. It represents my data just to well to give it up.
So is there a nicer way of cutting down a structured array in rows and columns without converting it to a normal numpy array?

Cheerse

Comment: what do you exactly want to achieve here? what's your desired output? `2`?

Comment: Hi. I'm not looking for an way to achieve something else than what you see above. I just hope somebody could point me a more easy way. It took me a long time to get what you see above, and I think its not an elegant soultion. I was hoping there is a method in numpy, that I dont know of, that simplifys the task above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your data is structured, wouldn't it be easier to access the values like this?

```
# get that array row
data[data['name']=='World'][0]
(2, 3.0, 'World')

# get individual value
data[data['name']=='World'][0][0]
2
```

#### Updated

To access multiple records, you can also use slicing or even list comprehension, something like this:

```
data[data['name'] != ''][1:]
array([(2, 3.0, 'World'), (4, 5.0, 'year')], 
      dtype=[('value1', '<i4'), ('value2', '<f4'), ('name', 'S6')])

data[data['name'] != ''][1:][1][0]
4

print [x[1] for x in data[data['name'] != ''][1:]]
[3.0, 5.0]
```

Comment: Hi, year that is a posibility, but it also results in an aditional loop if i want to acess multiple of the elements (say 100 or so, what I actually have). But at your example one can see my problem. I would like something like, data[data['name']=='World'][0][1:] to slice it wherever I like without writing for loops. But sadly this seems not possible.

Comment: @user3613114, you can still acess the data by slicing the array or list comprehension. See my updates.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help I apreciate it. Your idear is defenetly better than mine, because it skips this data.dtpye.names thing, and it goes in one. Maybe I want something that is not achievable but still I find the line: [x[1] for x in data[data['name'] != ''][1:]] to complicated for what it does. Maybe that is the best whay though.

Comment: @user3613114, list comprehension is quite efficient especially you need to work within many data/records, and no worries we're all here to try to help :)

Answer (score 1):

I find this easier with Pandas [`DataFrame`](https://jorisvandenbossche.github.io/example-pandas-docs/html-api-docs/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html)s:

```
import pandas as pd
a=pd.DataFrame(data)
a
   value1  value2   name
0       1       2  Hello
1       2       3  World
2       4       5   year

a[a.name=='World']
   value1  value2   name
1       2       3  World
```

Comment: Hi Thanks four your suggestion. I know of pandas and I though about the use of it as well, but for the moment I like to not pull in more dependencys of my code. However, I think still this doesnt satisfy by problem, because a[a.name=='World'] is not slicable with [1:] syntax or so? Correct me if I'm wrong